# A single JAX-RS WAR running on TOMCAT (not TOMEE), Websphere, Webslogic, JBOSS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, war

My question is : Is it possible to have a single WAR (with or without web.xml, don't matter) using JAX-RS (any implementation), using or not using Application class (declared or not), that runs without ANY changes on TOMCAT (not TOMEE), WebSphere, Weblogic and JBOSS ? 
Can someone point any complete sample running, please ?

Comment: It is possible with some configurations on the mentioned app servers.

Comment: Sorry, I read a lot of threads about that, and cannot see how it is possible.

Comment: It is not simple , you need to make changes in deployment descriptors like

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward, By default tomcat does not provide any JAX-RS implementation jars. So you need to bundle with you war to work in tomcat. For other Application servers you need to make changes in deployment descriptors to use war supplied JAX-RS implementaion.

For jboss you need to provide WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml 
For Eblogic you need to provide WEB-INF/weblogic.xml, 
Similarly you need to change ClassLoading in WebSphere

Comment: Provide a implementation jar is not a problem. I can put them just in <server>/lib of tomcat, and leave other servers with their own implementation. The problem seems to be deploy descriptor (web.xml). Do you have any idea ?